# How to return the N documents closest to a specific key from a couchdb view

Tags: view, couchdb, limit

I have a view on a couchdb database which exposes a certain document property as a key:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.docType && doc.docType === 'CARD') {
    if (doc.elo) {
      emit(doc.elo, doc._id);
    } else {
      emit(1000, doc._id);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm interested in querying this db for the (say) 25 documents with keys closest to a given input. The only thing I can think to do is to set a search range and make repeated queries until I have enough results:

```
// pouchdb's query fcn
function getNresultsClosestToK(key: number, limit: number) {
  let range = 20;
  do {

      cards = await this.db.query('elo', {
        limit,
        startkey: (key - range).toString(),
        endkey: (key + range).toString()
      });

      range += 20;
    } while (cards.rows.length < limit)

    return cards;
}
```

But this may require several calls and is inefficient. Is there a way to pass a single key and a limit to couch and have it return the `limit` documents closest to the supplied key?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to query for a specific key, then return 12 results before the key, the key itself, and 12 results after the key, for a total of 25 results.

The most direct way to do this is with two queries against your view, with the proper combination of `startkey`, `limit`, and `descending` values.

For example, to get the key itself, and the 12 values following, [query your view](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/views.html#db-design-design-doc-view-view-name) with these options:

- startkey: <your key>
- limit: 13
- descending: false

Then to get the 12 entries before your key, perform a query with the following options:

- startkey: <your key>
- limit: 13
- descending: true

This will give you two result sets, each with (a maximum of) 13 items. Note that your target key will be repeated (it's in each result set). You'll then need to combine the two result sets.

Note this does have a few limitations:

1. It returns a *maximum* of 26 results. If your data does not contain 12 values before or after your target key, you'll get fewer than 26 results.
2. If you have duplicate keys, you may get unexpected results. In particular:

   - If your target key is duplicated, you'll get 25 - N unique results (where N is the number of duplicates of your target key)
   - If your non-target keys are duplicated, you have no way of guaranteeing which of the duplicate keys will be returned, so performing the same query multiple times may result in different return values.

Comment: This does not quite match my intention, but it is close enough to be very useful. Thank you. To clarify: say keys [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 67827] exist in the db, and I asked for the 3 (limit) results closest to 9 (key). Desired return would be [6,7,8], not [7,8,67827]. Luckily I can rely on my keys in this case to be approximately normally distributed, so extreme case like this are unlikely.